# AngularJS - I don't understand why factory is always undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I defined a factory that makes a get request but when I inject it in a controller it always throws an undefined error.

This is the factory:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular
        .module('myApp');

    app.factory('homeFactory', homeFactory);

    function homeFactory ($q, $http, $location) {
        var data = {};

        data.getProducts = getProducts;

        function getProducts() {
            return $http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/products')
                .error(errorMessage);
        }

        function errorMessage(response) {
            console.log('There was an error', response);
        }

        return data;
    }

})();
```

This is the controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular
        .module('myApp');

    app.controller('homeController', homeController);

    homeController.$inject =[homeFactory];

    function homeController(homeFactory) {
        var home = this;
        homeFactory.getProducts()
            .success(success);

        function success(jsonData, statusCode) {
            console.log('The request was successful', statusCode);
            console.dir(jsonData);
            home.products = jsonData;
        }
    }
})();
```

It appears to be ok, but the console throws:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: homeFactory is not defined
```

Comment: If the error occurs in your controller, you should probably show that code (and the actual **error message in full**). Use the un-minified version of `angular.js` for more verbose error messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your DI annotation. You should only use strings

```
homeController.$inject = ['homeFactory'];
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation

> The $inject property is an array of **service names** to inject.

Answer (score 1):

The controller function supports dependency injection. You don't need to use the $injector directly. Try this:

```
 var app = angular
    .module('myApp');

 app.controller('homeController', homeController);


function homeController(homeFactory) {
    var home = this;
    homeFactory.getProducts()
        .success(success);

    function success(jsonData, statusCode) {
        console.log('The request was successful', statusCode);
        console.dir(jsonData);
        home.products = jsonData;
    }
}
```

The angular runtime will find the homeFactory service, and automatically pass it to your controller function when it's called.

Comment: while that may work in development, if these scripts are minified for production, this will break.  using `$inject` is actually recommended to avoid issues with minification.  However, as another answer suggested, `$inject` requires a string, which is where the problem lies.

Answer (score -1):

In controller you shall put factory in dependecies

```
app.controller('homeController', ['homeFactory', '$scope', 
    function (homeFactory, $scope){
        //scope code goes here
    }]
);
```

Comment: the poster is using `$inject` rather than the array injection.  Also, there is no need to inject `$scope` if you aren't using it.